# Best action to call add_rewrite_rule

Tags: rewrite-rules

In Codex I found that the best action to call add_rewrite_rule is the init action. So in this way the function is called every time the site load. But to save the rule in rewrite_rules option it would be better to call it in register_activation_hook?

Answer (score 1):

Rules should be added on `init` because other code might flush rewrite rules, which would cause your rules to disappear.